# Which opensource package most closely replicates the creation of Perl CPAN web site?

Tags: perl, content-management-system, wiki, cpan, autohotkey

I want to create an opensource module sharing website for autohotkey that is functionally similar to CPAN for perl modules.  I realize the autohotkey forum has a section to cover this, but it's using a forum and does not have the benefits that cpan has.  You have to weed through too many threads and you don't get consistent packaging of the component or consistent documentation.

Is there a wiki or cms or other opensource package that will allow me to quickly set up a "CPAN like site" for autohotkey components?

Important features:
1. search and categorization of modules
2. user star rating/ranking of modules
3. anyone should be able to author and maintain their module on the site
4. NOT thread based, but user feedback/comments for modules is ok

Comment: Similar stuff for other languages: http://ctan.org http://openjsan.org http://hackage.haskell.org http://ccan.ozlabs.org

Comment: Sounds like a decent task for the webframework of your choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

[CPANHQ](https://github.com/bricas/cpanhq) should have at least some features that you described, but surely no feature 3.

P.S. See also [PGXN](http://pgxn.org/) - CPAN for PostgreSQL extensions.